# Scroll single ListTile in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

Scroll single ListTile in ListView

```
class MainScreen extends MvcScreen<MainScreenController> {
  @override
  MainScreenController initController() => MainScreenController();

  @override
  Widget defaultScreenLayout(
      ScreenParameters screenParameters, MainScreenController controller) {
    return _tabsLayout;
  }

  Widget get _tabsLayout => DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(AppScaffold().title),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
          drawer: TelegramDrawer(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff65a9e0),
            child: Icon(Icons.create),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          body: _body,
        ),
      );

  Widget get _body => Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: _chatsListView),
        ],
      ).paddingAll(0);

  Widget get _chatsListView => Container(
        child:
            ListView.builder(itemCount: 1, itemBuilder: channelListItemBuilder),
      );

  Widget channelListItemBuilder(context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        radius: 28,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.archive,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        "Archived Chats",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain about what you want to achieve

Comment: I need srollable ListTile even ListView empty

Answer (score 0):

Once you wrap ListView in the column it does not allow you to scroll view. Therefore here I've changed the code:

```
Widget get _body => Expanded(child:Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
     Expanded(child: _chatsListView),
   ],
  ).paddingAll(0));
```